# How get object value?

Tags: c++, com

My program have to communicate with another through #import directive. It creates a new document and places TextFrame on it with default parameters

```
HRESULT hr = CoInitialize(NULL);
_ApplicationPtr myApp("InDesign.Application");

DocumentPtr myDoc = myApp->ActiveDocument;
PagePtr myPage = myDoc->Pages->Item[1L];
TextFramePtr myTextFrame = myPage->TextFrames->Add(); // create frame on Page
TextFramePtr myTextFrame_2 = myPage->TextFrames->Item[2L]; // Get second frame on Page;
```

TextFrame object has method GeometricBounds which changes frame size. Here is my code to set frame size:

```
double mySize[4] = {12.7, 12.7, 66.7, 83.2};
SAFEARRAY * Bound;
VARIANT Array;
Array.vt =   VT_ARRAY | VT_R8;
Bound = SafeArrayCreateVector(VT_R8, 1, 4); 
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
long index = i + 1;
SafeArrayPutElement(Bound, &index, &mySize[i]); 
}
Array.parray = Bound; 
myTextFrame->GeometricBounds = Array;
```

Here is the frame I create, but how can I get size of another frame, already existing in document?

Property GeometricBounds As Variant The bounds of the TextFrame excluding the stroke width, in the format [y1, x1, y2, x2], which give the coordinates of the top-left and bottom-right corners of the bounding box. as Array of 4 Units (Doubles or Strings)

The description of a method in the TLB file:

```
Frame : IDispatch
{
// Property data
__declspec(property(get=GetGeometricBounds,put=PutGeometricBounds))
_variant_t GeometricBounds;
...

// Methods: 
void PutGeometricBounds (
const _variant_t & _arg1 );
_variant_t GetGeometricBounds ( );
....
}
```

Comment: What is `myTextFrame`?

Comment: myTextFrame - element of collection TextFrames (Interface TextFrames). I updated the question

Answer (score 0):

Accessing the elements of a `SAFEARRAY` is a matter of calling:

- [SafeArrayGetLBound](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221622.aspx): Returns the lower bound for any dimension of a safe array.
- [SafeArrayGetUBound](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221584.aspx): Returns the upper bound for any dimension of a safe array.
- [SafeArrayGetElement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221255.aspx):Retrieves a single element of the array.

Comment: I need casting "GeometricBounds" to SafeArray?

Comment: Since we don't know, what `myTextFrame->GeometricBounds` is, you'll have to work that out yourself.